# Python Colorchooser

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, colors

So I have some code

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
def colorcode():
    color = askcolor()
    color = color[:2]
    return color
print(colorcode())
```

Say I click blue.
The response is:
`((0.0, 0.0, 255.99609375), '#0000ff')`
How can I get only the hexidecimal?
*EG:*

```
>>>print(colorcode())
-----
|   | The window <-
-----
('#0000ff')
```

OR even better, just **plain** #0000ff
Thanks!

Comment: `return color[1]`, by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex value is in the second position (1 since python's iterables are zero-indexed), so this simple code should do :

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
def colorcode():
    return askcolor()[1]
```